# How can I check if UIImageView is collided with any other view?

Tags: ios, ios4

I have one UIImageView and number of UIImageView which are entering in screen after some time interval. I want to check if that one ImageView is collided with any others.

Please help me.

Comment: Generally, you can check `CGRectIntersectsRect()` to see if two `CGRect` structures (such as the frames of two `UIImageView` objects) intersect. The question is, though, how your `UIImageView` objects are moving. Can you clarify that?

Comment: By how they are moving he means are you using some type of timer loop or UIView Animations?

Comment: I have used CGRectIntersectsRect(). But i want to compares that single UIImageView with others. Others are entering on screen after 10 seconds, i am using a timer loop for that.Each generated view is moving continuously on screen, and after that i am adding that generated UIImageView in a mutable array. So now, problem is that i need to compare frame of that single imageview with the others which are continuosly increasing in number. and the array is also continuously updating. So how can i achieve this?

Comment: Got it. I'm not sure why you wouldn't just then do fast enumeration through the `UIImageView` objects in your `NSMutableArray`, looking for collisions via `CGRectIntersectsRect()`, one by one. It doesn't seem very efficient, but I don't know of a better way to do it. If you start to see performance problems as the number of `UIImageView` objects increase, maybe you can pursue using the iOS built-in animation techniques rather than using `NSTimer` to manually animate yourself, as I would have thought that using `NSTimer` would be less efficient. Anyway, I've modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The general process for detecting collisions between rectangular shaped views is to use [`CGRectIntersectsRect()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntersectsRect) to see if the frames of two views intersect. So, if you have a `NSMutableArray` of `UIImageView` objects, you can perform a fast enumeration through them and look for the collision, something like:

```
for (UIView* view in self.imageViewsArray)
{
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view.frame, viewToDetectCollisionWith.frame))
    {
        // do whatever you want when you detect the collision
    }
}
```

Or, you can use the `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` which uses fast enumeration, but gives you both the numeric index, `idx`, and the individual `UIView` objects in the array in a single statement:

```
[self.imageViewsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(view.frame, viewToDetectCollisionWith.frame))
    {
        // do whatever you want when you detect the collision
    }
}];
```

---

**Original answer:**

If you're animating the `UIImageView` objects via the various automated animation techniques, you have to use something like [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) to check for collisions because iOS is taking care of the animation and you otherwise are not informed of the `frame` of the various views in the middle of an animation. The `CADisplayLink` informs your app every time the animation has progressed, so you get information about the location of views as the animation progresses. Sounds like you're not availing yourself of built in animation techniques, but rather using a `NSTimer` to manually adjust frames, so you might not need the below code. But if you ever pursue a more automated animation, you can use the following technique.

What you can do is use a [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) to get information about the screen while the animation is in progress:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkHandler)];
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

You might even want to store that in a class property so you can add it and remove it as the view appears and disappears:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayLinkHandler)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [self.displayLink removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    self.displayLink = nil;
}
```

Then, you can start your animation. I'm just using the standard block-based animation to continually animate the changing of two image view frames, but you'll obviously do whatever is appropriate for your app:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4.0
                      delay:0.5
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                 animations:^{
                     self.imageView1.frame = ... // I set the frame here
                     self.imageView2.frame = ... // I set the frame here
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

Now I can detect when these two frames collide (i.e., whether their frames intersect) with this `CADisplayLink` handler which grabs the relevant [`presentationLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer) properties to get the "in progress" frame coordinates:

```
- (void)displayLinkHandler
{
    id presentationLayer1 = self.imageView1.layer.presentationLayer;
    id presentationLayer2 = self.imageView2.layer.presentationLayer;

    BOOL nowIntersecting = CGRectIntersectsRect([presentationLayer1 frame], [presentationLayer2 frame]);

    // I'll keep track of whether the two views were intersected in a class property,
    // and therefore only display a message if the intersected state changes.

    if (nowIntersecting != self.wasIntersected)
    {
        if (nowIntersecting)
            NSLog(@"imageviews now intersecting");
        else
            NSLog(@"imageviews no longer intersecting");

        self.wasIntersected = nowIntersecting;
    }
}
```

By the way, you may need to add Quartz 2D, the `QuartzCore.framework`, to your project. See the [Project Editor Help](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/AddingaLibrarytoaTarget.html).

Comment: Thanks Rob.. I just used a for loop consisting CGRectIntersectsRect() method. and its working properly. its checking collision with each newly generated UIImageView.